# How to use anchors in Spotify apps?

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to scroll to the top of the page when changing the argument of the spotify url?

I use this javascript function

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
            var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
            tabs();
            models.application.observe(models.EVENT.ARGUMENTSCHANGED, tabs);
            function tabs() {
                var args = models.application.arguments;
                console.log(args[0]);
                $('.section').hide();
                $('#'+args[0]).show();
            }
        });
```

Every time I switch to another section I want to scroll to the top of the section. Is this possible? Similar to anchors like #top.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use:

document.location = '#' + args[0];

And have different sections with same ids as the tabs.

Comment: Be careful though, the app might be rejected if you use tabs this way. Each tab should feel as a separate page. My app was rejected (partly) because of this.